# View code with different indentation than saved to disk

Tags: indentation

I work on some projects with indentation styles that I find really irritating.  I'd like to view the code with a certain indentation style, but always save to disk with the prescribed indentation style.

Specifically,  I like emacs default style of indentation on multi-line function arguments...

```
void foo(int a, int b,
         string c)
```

But the project is tab-only, single indent on everything...

```
void foo(int a, int b,
    string c)
```

Can I **see** the first case, but share the second?

Comment: What about: disable auto-revert mode, then run a command (e.g., [`astyle`](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)) which formats the file to your team's style in your `after-save-hook`

Comment: have you considered a version-control level formatting hook, e.g. git pre-commit hook?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious approach to this would be to

- indent a copy of the buffer using `c-mode`; and then
- put the copy's indent as display properties on the indentation space in the original buffer.

Note 1: Implementing this while keeping the ability to edit the buffer could be a nightmare, so I'd make the buffer read-only.
Note 2: Text properties are much faster than overlays, so I'd use them.  Unless in the odd case where the original buffer's indent is 0 and `c-mode`'s is not.

Comment: This can be done with text properties by adding extra font-locking keywords. I'm more concerned about figuring out how the indent should be displayed instead.